# Adding Code to Methods with Parameters that Are Decorated with Attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, sourcegenerators

So I'm just doing this for a bit of personal experimentation. I've developed a bunch of validators that follow this interface:

```cs
public interface IParameterValidator<in T>
{
    public void Validate(T param);
}
```

For instance, an email validator:

```cs
public class EmailValidator: IParameterValidator<Email>
{
    private static readonly Regex EmailRegex = new(@"^[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))$");


    public void Validate(Email email)
    {
        if (!EmailRegex.IsMatch(email.ToString())) throw new InvalidParameterException(nameof(email));
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is decorate parameters wherever I may find them and then have them automagically validated with the appropriate validator. So this is the attribute I think I need:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class ValidateParameterAttribute: Attribute
{
    public Type ValidatorType { get; }

    public ValidateParameterAttribute(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (!validatorType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IParameterValidator<>))) throw new("Must provide a validator!");
    }
}
```

Now, as far as I'm aware, there's no simple way to simple say "wherever we see this attribute on a method/property, run this method". I also know I could call my method through some sort of extra class that looks for these properties, but I don't really want to do that. Along the lines of `MethodInfo.ValidatedInvoke(object[] params parms)`. However, I don't want to do that, I want it to "just work".

Essentially I'd want to turn this:

```cs
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

Into something like this (probably store the validators in some register or something but that's not important):

```cs
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    Activator.CreateInstance<NameValidator>().Validate(name);
    Activator.CreateInstance<EmailValidator>().Validate(email);
    Activator.CreateInstance<AdultValidator>().Validate(dateOfBirth);
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

So I've had a google around and I've come across Source Generators. I'm fairly sure that I can achieve this with one of those, however, it's not something I've ever touched before. I reckon if I can work out how to call this method in the right places using the source generator, this should work:

```cs
private string GetValidationString(MethodInfo method)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new();
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
    if (parameters.Length == 0) return string.Empty;
    foreach (ParameterInfo info in parameters)
    {
        ValidateParameterAttribute? validationAttribute = info.GetCustomAttribute<ValidateParameterAttribute>();
        if (validationAttribute is null) continue;
        builder.Append($"Activator.CreateInstance<{validationAttribute.ValidatorType.Name}>().Validate({info.Name});\n");
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

So my question really boils down to, how do I get my source generator to add that code in the right place?

---

#### EDIT:

So following some advice in the comments, I'm now trying to get this working with `Someta.Fody` and its method interceptors.

So far, I've got this attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ValidatedMethodAttribute: Attribute, IMethodInterceptor
{
    public object Invoke(MethodInfo methodInfo, object instance, Type[] typeArguments, object[] arguments, Func<object[], object> invoker)
    {
        Attribute[]? attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes().Where(att => att.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(IParameterValidator<>))).ToArray();
        // Do my thing
        return invoker.Invoke(arguments);
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the build, something weird is going on with Fody but I can't quite work out what this issue is..?

```
  Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
Failed to execute weaver /home/james/.nuget/packages/someta.fody/1.2.1/build/../weaver/Someta.Fody.dll
Type:
System.Exception
StackTrace:
   at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 222
   at InnerWeaver.Execute() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 112
Source:
FodyIsolated
TargetSite:
Void ExecuteWeavers()
System.Type was somehow not found.  Aborting.
Type:
System.InvalidOperationException
StackTrace:
   at Someta.Fody.CecilExtensions.Initialize(ModuleDefinition moduleDefinition, TypeSystem typeSystem, AssemblyNameReference soMeta)
   at Someta.Fody.ModuleWeaver.Execute()
   at InnerWeaver.ExecuteWeavers() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 186
Source:
Someta.Fody
TargetSite:
Boolean Initialize(Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition, Fody.TypeSystem, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference)
```

I'm wondering if the fact that I'm building this on Linux might be an issue given the references to a non-existent C drive in that error message?

Comment: *I also know I could call my method through some sort of extra class that looks for these properties* Yes, that is the way to do it. If you don't want to do it that way, maybe attributes is not the right approach.

Comment: @JohnWu The reason behind not wanting to do it that way is that I want to be able to just add my package, then add the attributes to code that already exists and have it just work with no need for any additional setup

Comment: It's late, I'm going to bed, but this repo may hold the answers, so I'm going to leave it here so I can find it tomorrow. If nobody's beaten me to it, I think I'll be able to answer my own question then! https://github.com/mhmd-azeez/FunWithSourceGenerators/blob/master/FunWithSourceGenerators/AsyncifyGenerator.cs

Comment: are you looking to emulate the behavior of the `ValidationAttribute` class?

Comment: Similar to aye @ShaiCohen - Although having done some more research I don't think a code generator can do it, I think I need to do some weaving with something like Fody

Comment: @ScottishTapWater you say, "So my question really boils down to, how do I get my source generator to add that code in the right place?"  What does that mean exactly?  Source generators can only generate code that you yourself could have written.  So the best way for us to be able to help is for you to show us the code you hope to be generated.  For example, are you hoping some generated code would call `GetValidationString`?  If so, then please show us an example of non-generated code that does this and we can offer tips on how you can generate it.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I thought I'd done this, so `GetValidationString` was the method I wanted to call from within my source generator against a method to insert my validation code at the start of a method. I've added an extra section though to make this a bit more clear. I've since done some more research and I don't think I can actually do this with a code generator, I think I'd need to do code weaving with something like Fody but I've not been able to work that out for certain yet

Comment: @ScottishTapWater, you may well be correct, but I'd really love to see some sample code that calls `GetValidationString` (you still haven't shown that).  I have a fair amount of experience with both source generators and Fody, so can probably give you a definitive answer.  Presumably you have a method that has a parameter decorated with your attribute and somewhere in that method you'd like code to be generated that calls your `GetValidationString` method.  If I could just see an example of that, I'd have a great sense of what your best options are.

Comment: @KirkWoll I was busy adding it in as you commented :) I think that's what you were asking for... `GetValidationString` was going to be called from within my source generator to create  those `Activator...Validate()` calls

Comment: @ScottishTapWater thanks, that absolutely clarified things for me.  I think I'm just going to provide an answer to enumerate your options but unfortunately you're correct that you won't be able to get precisely what you want from source generators in your scenario, and I'll explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the short answer is that it will not be possible to arrive at the exact solution you are hoping for with source generators.  The reason is that one of the absolute design philosophies of source generators (which I find dismaying, but can understand the rationale) was to actively disallow mutation of existing source files through the use of source generators.  To put it another way, you can't actually modify the code of any of your hand-written classes.  Source generators are [strictly additive](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#proposal).  The reason it can still be very powerful is through the use of partial classes (a type whose definition is declared in multiple files).

With that preamble out of the way, let's look a bit more closely at your exact use-case.  You have this method:

```
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

And you want to turn it into this method:

```
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    Activator.CreateInstance<NameValidator>().Validate(name);
    Activator.CreateInstance<EmailValidator>().Validate(email);
    Activator.CreateInstance<AdultValidator>().Validate(dateOfBirth);
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

As you can see, the outcome you desire requires *modifying* your `CreateUser` method, which isn't possible.

One solution that will get you half-way there would be to generate a custom validate method for any method with a parameter decorated with the `ValidateParameter` attribute.  For example, you *could* generate this method:

```
// Generated
private void ValidateCreateUser(Name name, Email email, DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    Activator.CreateInstance<NameValidator>().Validate(name);
    Activator.CreateInstance<EmailValidator>().Validate(email);
    Activator.CreateInstance<AdultValidator>().Validate(dateOfBirth);
}
```

Then in your `CreateUser` method you would be able to call this method directly yourself:

```
public User CreateUser( [ValidateParameter(typeof(NameValidator))] Name name,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(EmailValidator))] Email email,
                        [ValidateParameter(typeof(AdultValidator))] DateOfBirth dateOfBirth)
{
    ValidateCreateUser(name, email, dateOfBirth);  // You'd add this line yourself
    User user = new(name, email, dateOfBirth);
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    return user;
}
```

Whether this is a sufficiently successful outcome only you can say.

If you want to get to exactly the solution you were hoping for, I'm afraid your suspicion in the comments that you'd have to resort to Fody is accurate.  Creating a custom Fody plugin requires a pretty deep understanding of both Fody and the C# IL.

Shameless plug: I maintain a Fody library called [Someta](https://github.com/kswoll/someta) that would make it pretty easy for you to accomplish this via [method interceptors](https://github.com/kswoll/someta/blob/master/Someta.Docs/ExtensionPoints/MethodInterceptors.md).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give Someta a go... If I get stuck with it are you happy for me to ping you for assistance?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater, yup, of course! :)

Comment: Appreciate it! If I work it out on my own I might edit it onto the end of your answer too, may as well have it here for posterity

Comment: For sure, sounds good. 

Comment: Added an edit to the question because Fody doesn't seem to be behaving right. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm what version of .NET you are using?  It's basically failing to find the runtime.

Comment: `dotnet --version ---> 6.0.102` would I need to fork and retarget Someta?

Comment: Welp, that's definitely the version I typically use.  Any chance you could post a zip of a project that demonstrates the issue as an issue in my repo?

Comment: I've created this issue: https://github.com/kswoll/someta/issues/19 Thanks for all of your help on this!